# Why do Android callback methods' name start with 'on'?

Tags: java, android

I'm just curious. (Maybe not only in Android)

Comment: Well, why not? It’s just a convention to make them all similar. And btw. many other languages (or rather frameworks) do this as well for methods that are internally called and may be overridden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android's callbacks respond to events. You react to events when they occur. So when `an event occurs` you `do something`. Therefore:

```
onOccurrence() {
  doSomething;
}
```

It's just a convention.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Java programming is designed to be readable, and although at times it does appear bloated, it is still very readable, especially Android. I'm guessing the SDK developers wanted to give names that would be read in a very readable manor.

```
onPause(){
Do stuff here when app is paused.
}
```

How more obvious can it get?

Answer (score 0):

As they correspond to "events" and in Android all "event" method start with the "on" prefix. I really didn't like this at the beginning as it's not a java convention, but, after all, why not.